# Creating a status bar that can move constantly in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want to do is create a status bar, that when you click on it the bar will go up. I am also not using jquery. I was going to have multiple images, that represented each point of the status bar, then display them as an image, which would work but I do not know if it is possible to link js variables into html. I also found I could use something like this

HTML

```
<div class="skill_bar" style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:50px; z-index:2">
<div class="skill_bar_progress skill_one"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.skill_bar {
width:20px;
height:50px;
background:#c0c0c0;
margin-bottom:5px;
}

.skill_bar_progress {
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:#00f;
}
```

But that did not work so well because it only worked once and I could not find a way to change it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener to the click event on the status bar. That function is going to move the status bar up.

Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            #statusBar {
                background-color: orange;
                width: 200px;
                height: 100px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
                var statusBar = document.querySelector("#statusBar");
                var top = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(statusBar).top);

                statusBar.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    top = top - 10;
                    statusBar.style.top = top + "px";
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="statusBar">Status</div>
    </body>
</html>
```